Can not patchValue of PrimeNG p-editor component
I created a form that makes use of p-editor element to write rich formatted text, but i ran into a problem, the editor creates and submits the rich text, but when we want to update the form with a value from the server, using the angular reactive form patchValue method doesn't update the editor as required. Here is my code
Template:
<form>
  <div class="col-12 my-3">
      <label class="small font-bold" for="content" i18n>Requirments</label>
      <p-editor formControlName="content" id="content" placeholder="content..." [style]="{ height: '200px' }"></p-editor>
    </div>
</form>

component:
export class SampleComponent implements OnChanges {

 @Input() data?: {content: string};
 formEditor: FormGroup

 constructor(
    private _fb: FormBuilder,
  ) 
 {
  this.formEditor = this._fb.group({
     content: ["", Validators.required]
  })
 }

 ngOnChanges() {
// I verified and indeed the data comes when there is a change 
    if (this.data) {
      this.patchEditorForm(this.data);
    }
 }

 private patchEditorForm = (data: {content: string}) => {
    this.formEditor.patchValue({
      content: post.content
    })
 }

}

I use the AfterViewInit and Angular @ViewChild decorator but it didn't still work

I finally figured out a way around it using the @ViewChild decorator in Angular. Here's how I modified the code to achieve the said objectives:.
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { EditorModule, Editor } from 'primeng/editor';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, EditorModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="formEditor">
      <div class="col-12 my-3">
          <label class="small font-bold" for="content">Content:</label>
          <p-editor #editor formControlName="content" id="content" placeholder="content..."></p-editor>
        </div>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() data?: { content: string };
  formEditor: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  // using @ViewChild decorator
  @ViewChild('editor') public editor!: Editor

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.formEditor = this._fb.group({
      content: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    // I verified and indeed, the data comes when there is a change
    if (this.data) {
      // make use of the writeValue() of the editor object
      this.editor.writeValue(this.data.content);
    }
  }
}

Also, make sure you run the command npm install --save @types/quill, because when trying out this method, I encountered an error with something having to do with an import of Delta from the library.

This MR fix the issue, just to wait the merge
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/pull/16826

data is an object, objects are stored as references to memory in javascript, the thing to note is that, even when you change the content which is an inner property of data, the memory reference to data stays the same, so even when there was a data change in the inner properties, angular has no way to identify something has changed.
Solution is to change the memory reference, a common way to do this is called object destructuring, when we create a new array and update the original properties into the new one, the command will be this.data = { ...this.data };
After doing this the change will get detected. Working example below!
FULL CODE:
MAIN
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'editor-basic-demo',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  template: `
    <app-child [data]="data"/>
  `,
})
export class EditorBasicDemo {
  name = 'Angular';
  data = {
    content: '',
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.data.content = `${Math.random()}`;
      this.data = { ...this.data }; // use object destructuring to create a new reference of memory for the array
      // this will cause angular to detect a change and trigger ngOnChanges when changed!
    }, 2000);
  }
}

CHILD
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { EditorModule } from 'primeng/editor';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, EditorModule],
  template: `
  asd
    <form [formGroup]="formEditor">
      <div class="col-12 my-3">
          <label class="small font-bold" for="content">Requirments</label>
          <p-editor formControlName="content" id="content" placeholder="content..."></p-editor>
        </div>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() data?: { content: string };
  formEditor: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.formEditor = this._fb.group({
      content: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    // I verified and indeed the data comes when there is a change
    if (this.data) {
      this.patchEditorForm(this.data);
    }
  }

  private patchEditorForm = (data: { content: string }) => {
    this.formEditor.patchValue({
      content: data.content,
    });
  };
}

Stackblitz Demo

I worked on this idea, and the change detection works like it detects the data. I think the problem lies in patching the value of the PrimeNG p-editor. For one reason or another, it just won't work, and I searched the internet to find a way to do it but couldn't find it. Are there any other ways to patch this value or any other approach to it?

@MofiroJean check your version of prime ng, then go to GitHub in branches choose your version and open the package.json, there check the version of quill, ensure you have the same version installed in your project, you can also check the node_modules folder inside your project for package.json

Okay great let me try that, I never thought of that.
